# CKQuery is very slow using "IN" predicate

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

Let me start by saying, no this has nothing to do with trying to update the UI in a background thread.

I'm trying to query some photo records in CloudKit, each contains an eventId, thumbnail and photo (among other things). Since I'm still developing this, there are only about 75 photo records in the public database.

My predicate is:
`let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "eventId IN %@", myConcertIds)` where myConcertIds is an array of strings. In this case it has 16 elements.

This takes about 10 seconds to come back. Thinking maybe it was slow transferring the images back I switched from a simple `publicDB.performQuery` to a CKQueryOperation and only specified the eventId and thumbnail as the desired keys. This still took about 10 seconds.

You can see here, the time from when I add the operation, to when the first record completion block fires is 11 seconds

```
2015-11-04 20:51:43.043 CKDataStack.getAllPhotoAlbumCovers[553]: Starting Query Operation (eventId IN %@ - myConcertIds)
2015-11-04 20:51:54.054 CKDataStack.getAllPhotoAlbumCovers[529]: Got one record
```

I have to assume this is due to the IN predicate since == queries come back very fast but I can't think of a more efficient way to do this. I need to query for records with an eventId that matched a value in an array. Eventually there will be thousands of records and this will only get slower

Any suggestions? 11 seconds is an eternity of waiting for a user

**UPDATES:** (from comments)

I wasn't sure so I revised the debug print and, yes I'm only getting the two keys I asked for

```
2015-11-05 08:14:8.008 CKDataStack.getAllPhotoAlbumCovers[553]: Starting Query Operation (eventId IN %@ - myConcertIds) 
2015-11-05 08:14:16.016 CKDataStack.getAllPhotoAlbumCovers[529]: Got one record with keys ["eventId", "thumbnail"]
```

---

as another test I set `operation.resultsLimit = 1` and it still takes 8 seconds

---

I changed the predicate to `NSPredicate(value: true)` to test my assumption, it still takes 10 seconds.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't get the images itself anymore? 10 seconds could be normal for transmitting 16 images. The number of records in your recordType should have almost no influence on the speed. The number of records in the result will have impact on the speed. I found out that it's better to keep all your images in a separate table and query them independent of the data.

Comment: I wasn't sure so I revised the debug print and, yes I'm only getting the two keys I asked for `2015-11-05 08:14:8.008 CKDataStack.getAllPhotoAlbumCovers[553]: Starting Query Operation (eventId IN %@ - myConcertIds)
2015-11-05 08:14:16.016 CKDataStack.getAllPhotoAlbumCovers[529]: Got one record with keys ["eventId", "thumbnail"]`

Comment: as another test I set `operation.resultsLimit = 1` and it still takes 8 seconds.

Comment: @EdwinVermeer Do you store the metadata in one table and the asset in another by reference? I can try that but it will require some changes, I just want to be sure before I start

Comment: Since you probably want to query more often than you need the image, a separate table will make that easier. I used that in the demo of https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection

Comment: O sorry, wrong library. I meant https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao

Comment: Finally circled back around to this, I did make the schema changes suggested. While it was a useful change for other reasons it hasn't helped my query times. Times vary as high as 18 seconds sometimes.  Still stumped, any more ideas?